# Please pass either 'apiKey' or 'stripe' to StripeProvider

Tags: reactjs, next.js, stripe-payments

I've previously had this working just fine, but I am now stumped as to what is going on.   I'm using Next.js for SSR and my Pay element looks like so:

```
class Pay extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = { stripe: null };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    console.log(window.Stripe)
    this.setState({
      stripe: window.Stripe('pk_test_123'),
    });
  }

  render() {
    console.log(this.state)
    return (
      <StripeProvider apiKey={this.state.stripe}>
        <Elements>
          <InjectedCheckoutForm />
        </Elements>
      </StripeProvider>
    );
  }
}
```

The above throws the error:

> Please pass either 'apiKey' or 'stripe' to StripeProvider. If you're
>   using 'stripe' but don't have a Stripe instance yet, pass 'null'
>   explicitly.

What I'm confused about here though is, as it is, window, nor the state are logged as the page throws a 500 error.
If I remove the StripeProvider component, window.Stripe logs out fine, and this.state contains my Stripe state so I can't understand why its throwing the error.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## Why you're getting the error

`<StripeProvider />` wants the `apiKey` or `stripe` prop on the initial render as shown by the error.

On your initial render, `state.stripe` is `null`, and so subsequently `<StripeProvider apiKey=null>`. This raises the 500 error because only StripeProvider's `this.props.stripe` is null-checked so that it can understand there are some asynchronous things going on on the consumer's side.

https://github.com/stripe/react-stripe-elements/blob/master/src/components/Provider.js#L105

`this.props.apiKey` being `null` leads you to your error because `apiKey` is not treated the same way. https://github.com/stripe/react-stripe-elements/blob/master/src/components/Provider.js#L110

## Solution

**I think the problem though is that you're just using the wrong property. Switch from `StripeProvider.apiKey` to `StripeProvider.stripe`.** `apiKey` takes in a `string` type while `stripe` takes in a `StripeObject` (which is also what your `window.Stripe()` returns).

```
  <StripeProvider stripe={this.state.stripe}>
    <Elements>
      <InjectedCheckoutForm />
    </Elements>
  </StripeProvider>
```

Observe the code examples at https://github.com/stripe/react-stripe-elements#loading-stripejs-asynchronously and https://github.com/stripe/react-stripe-elements#server-side-rendering-ssr for more information.

Sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/x2r1pxwjqz

Try changing `stripe` -> `apiKey` to see the error pop up.

Comment: Ah damnit, how did I miss that. That's solved it, thanks!